# trying to traverse with multiple threads in orientdb

Tags: java, orientdb

I am trying to traverse in dfs fashion with multiple vertices as seed node. (start node). these are stored in a blocking queue. I am having consumer threads which takes one node at a time and perform dfs traversal. However i am getting a NPE. not sure whats wrong with the code. following is the code.

```
class Consumer implements Runnable{

private BlockingQueue<Vertex> queue;
private OrientBaseGraph graph;

public Consumer(BlockingQueue<Vertex> queue) {
    graph = DB.getFactory().getNoTx();  
    graph.makeActive();
    this.queue = queue;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    Vertex v = queue.poll();
    Stack<Vertex> stack = new Stack<>();
    stack.push(v);
    while(!stack.isEmpty()) {
        Vertex current = stack.pop();
        Iterable<Vertex> children = current.getVertices(Direction.OUT, "contains");
        for(Vertex child : children) {
            stack.push(child);
        }
    }           
}
```

}

How can i fix it or whats wrong with this implementation?

Comment: HI, what version are you using? Thx

Comment: 2.2.35 version.